# RSolve returns a wrong result, why?

Tags: bugs, difference-equations

I'm trying to solve the following recurrence relation: $ \begin{cases} u_{0} = a \\ u_{n + 1} = - \sum_{i = 0}^{n} u_{i} u_{n - i} \end{cases} $ 
Here is my Mathematica code:

```
InitialCondition = u[0] == a;
RecurenceRelation = u[n + 1] == - Sum[u[i] * u[n - i], {i, 0, n}];
RSolveValue[{InitialCondition, RecurenceRelation}, u[n], n ] /. n -> 0
```

I'm not quite sure why I get $-a$ as a result. I expected $+a$, since that's my initial condition. 
I'm new to Mathematica, so it's probably obvious, but I would really appreciate the help. 
Thank you!

Comment: Looks like a bug to me; please [report this to Support](https://www.wolfram.com/support/contact/).

Comment: (+1) Good catch! Btw, this is the recurrence relation for the Catalan numbers, [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number#First_proof), up to multiplying all $u$ by $-1$. See `CatalanNumber`.

Comment: All right, thanks for the advice, I've reported it to Support.

Comment: Could someone with access to older versions to check add the customary bug header?

Comment: @J.M. Same problem with 11.3 for Windows 32.  I have no older versions.

Comment: Bug still exists in version 13.2.0 (November 18, 2022)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A workaround,

```
Clear["Global`*"]

u[0] = a;
u[n_] := u[n] = -Sum[u[i]*u[n - i - 1], {i, 0, n - 1}];

seq = {#, u[#]} & /@ Range[0, 6]

(* {{0, a}, {1, -a^2}, {2, 2 a^3}, {3, -5 a^4}, {4, 14 a^5}, {5, -42 a^6}, 
  {6, 132 a^7}}
```

Using [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to generalize,

```
sol = FindSequenceFunction[seq, n] // FunctionExpand // Simplify

(* (4^n (-a)^n a Gamma[1/2 + n])/(Sqrt[π] Gamma[2 + n]) *)
```

Checking for larger values,

```
Table[sol, {n, 0, 50}] === Table[u[n], {n, 0, 50}]

(* True *)
```